# Why level 1,-1,2,3 in a data set containing 10 real numbers are the same? As shown in the following figure!

Tags: trees

Why level 1,-1,2,3 in a data set containing 10 real numbers are the same? As shown in the following figure!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

x = RandomReal[10, 10]

(* {8.76608, 5.21964, 0.862234, 3.77913, 0.116446, 9.27266, 5.43757, 
    4.79332, 2.45349, 7.59896} *)
```

As stated in the documentation:

`Level[x, 0]` is a `List` with no elements

```
Level[x, 0] === {}

(* True *)
```

`Level[x, {0}]` is a `List` of the whole expression

```
Level[x, {0}] === {x}

(* True *)
```

`Level[x, n]` for positive `n` is a `List` of all elements at level `1` through `n`. Since, in this case, there is only one level

```
Level[x, 1] === Level[x, 2] === Level[x, 3] === x

(* True *)
```

`Level[x, -1]`  is a `List` of all "atomic" (cannot be subdivided) elements

```
And @@ (AtomQ /@ x)

(* True *)
```

Since all of the elements of `x` are atomic

```
Level[x, -1] === x

(* True *)
```